# maxhttpHeaderSize in spring boot tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I need to limit the header size of request to 16KB in spring boot. I added the maxHttpHeaderSize flag to 16000 to do this.
I noticed that when I make a call from postman to test this out, the request starts failing(Request header is too large) from the time the header size is around 15KB. I was wondering what happens to the other 1KB?

Comment: 16000 bytes is equal to 15.625 KiB.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue with confusion of what a KB means. In your case, it's most likely the [Base 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte#Base_2_(1024_bytes)) value, which is 1024, not 1000. This means that 16000 bytes are actually around 15.7KB.

You can set the `maxHttpHeaderSize` either to 16 * 1024 = `16384`, or just to `16KB`, which should work if you have Spring Boot 2.1+

Also, this value limits not just one particular header field size, but the full HTTP header, including all field names and values. Postman may also include some hidden headers, like `Host`, `Content-Size`, `User-Agent`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Sergei . I changed the header size to 16384, I still get the error when the request header size is around 15.62kb. My application uses a very old version of spring boot 1.3.2.RELEASE. I am not sure if it has something to do with that too.

Comment: @sinsanarya it may also depend on how you measure the request header size. This value limits not just one particular header field, but the complete header size, including all field names and values.

Comment: yes. I have only one header as I am testing this out. No other headers.

Comment: Most likely Postman still adds some headers even if you don't explicitly specify them, like `Host`, `Content-Size`, `Content-Type`, `User-Agent` etc.

Comment: Ya I checked. Postman actually adds few headers even if I remove it. Request breaks after 15.8kb which is fine I guess. Pretty close to 16kb.